# Can we have a badge for controversy?

Tags: feature-request, badges

The [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) question on SO has been yoyoing for several days now, and has been opened and closed about 7 or 8 times I think. Why not have a badge for such controversial questions?

Comment: ...You've just earnt it.

Answer (score 14):

**No.**

I don't think this is behavior that the community wants to encourage. The yoyo-effect that is.

So I guess awarding a badge for it is not really the way to go.

Answer (score 10):

> Hey, I know! We could have a badge for
>   most flagged comment or most offensive
>   answer. And it should be gold!

The thing is, badges are supposed to encourage **positive behavior**. What you're suggesting is exactly the opposite. Questions like the [strongest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) already get plenty of badges for those involved. A lot of these controversial questions have a lot of votes, a lot of views and a lot of answers. Why award people a new badge?

Comment: No kidding... I'm the OP, I got 3 golds for the question and 1 gold for my answer in that same question, plus countless silvers and bronzes. I think it's enough :D

Comment: My thoughts exactly. By the way, congratulations on the badges!

Answer (score 2):

No...  If controversy was to be encouraged then there wouldn't be close reasons for subjective and argumentative.