# Is the Area 51 badge Great Question achieveable?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, area-51, badges

Some of the Area 51 badges have not been achieved by anyone but I wonder if Great Question is *achieveable*?

I presume the current definition is simply a takeover from the existing Q&As, like Meta StackOverflow. But I think it should be different on Area 51.

The **Great Question** badge requires 100 votes. But most people stop after 20 because that is the threshold to get an on or off topic question and people want to get their Q&A through the definition phase.

I don't think I've seen a question get near 100 votes - has anyone seen an example of that?

**Update:** based on the data provided by Emmett below, I thought the **Good Question** badge may be unachieveable (it requires 50 votes). However, 15 people have achieved it. On closer examination, this looks like a database issue.

Take Joel Spolsky's best question, *[Statistical Analysis: Joe is 8 years old, Mike is 10 years old, and Alice is 13. What is their MEDIAN age?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33/statistical-analysis/42#42)* This has 1 on topic vote and 22 off-topic. I make that 23. So how did he get the Good Question badge?!

**Update 2:** Removed the **bug tag** - it referred to the Good Question problem (people got it without having 50 votes - this was done during the setup / test phase of Area 51, see below comments).

**Final Update:** Please see also my related (follow-up) question here: [Why not replace Good & Great Question badges with a Top 5 badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59959/why-not-replace-good-great-question-badges-with-a-top-5-badge)

**Twenty months later:** it is [still not achieved](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges). Will you reconsider the implementation?

**Finally:** after the new implementation, [one person has got this badge](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40927/computer-security-hacking/41074#41074)!

Comment: As of right now, [this question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7794/scrum/7803#7803) on the Scrum proposal has the most votes (34).

Comment: The real question is - should you really care about getting badges on Area 51?

Comment: @Emmett - thanks. (How did you know?) I presume the 2 "not a good example" votes don't affect achieving 100 overall (not according to the badge definition, anyway)? Area 51 has been going, what, 3 months? And that's the best? Kind of confirms then that this is unachievable, right (assuming Normal distribution)?

Comment: @Farseeker - while that is true, that does not negate the question: the badges, if they exist, should be there for a reason and should therefore be achievable.

Comment: @Mark I have DB access ;)

Comment: @Emmett - correction - 15 people have the "Good Question" badge - this looks like an bug. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Mark Those badges were awarded in early June, before we imposed voting limits, and before we deleted all existing votes during a rep recalc.

Comment: @Emmett - aha, thanks for the reply. So they no one has come close to achieving even a *Good Question*, let alone a **Great Question**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We lowered the threshold for the Nice/Good/Great Question badges from 10/50/100 to 10/30/50.

As a result, 24 more people just earned Good Question.

As of right now, still no one has Great Question, but at least it seems slightly achievable now.

Comment: Thanks Emmett - nice to know that you are so responsive. I still wonder if Great is achieveable... time will tell...

Comment: one month + on, still no one is anywhere closer to achieving it. It's still **not achieveable**. Please reconsider the numbers (50 is *too high*) or this suggestion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59959/why-not-replace-good-great-question-badges-with-a-top-5-badge

Comment: Emmett - this is a *ping* to let you know that I've updated the question.

Comment: Noted, thanks. The `Great Question` badge clearly still isn't correctly calibrated. We're actually considering a major overhaul of A51 that may render this moot, so stay tuned..