# New Area 51 badge idea: Definer implies 10 on and 10 off votes

Tags: feature-request, area-51, badge-request

Part of the challenge of Area 51 is to think up great on and off topic questions. An even bigger challenge is to find questions that are right on the border to help define what the border is.

Hence this idea of a badge to reward those questions. Any question that earns 10 or more on topic votes *and* 10 or more on topic votes gets the badge.

(I thought of the name **Definer** for this badge but can anyone can think of a better name?)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52185/can-we-have-a-badge-for-controversy-on-area51

Comment: @KennyTM - yup, that's pretty much the same thing - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **[Can we have a badge for controversy – on Area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52185/can-we-have-a-badge-for-controversy-on-area51)**