# Can negatively-received [feature-request]s lead to a question ban?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Should a few negatively-receieved feature requests from the same user cause a question ban on meta?

Since voting on feature-requests is used to express the community's agreement/disagreement with the request (and not the quality of the post), I would think it doesn't, but I have been wrong many times before.

The reason I mention this is that [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162891/frederik-creemers) mentioned he got question-banned.  I know I can't see everything that goes into that (and I think only the devs know the specifics for obvious reasons), but that does not seem right to me. He only has 2 posts: One has been down-voted, the other has been closed. That doesn't seem like a [history of extremely poor questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60294/168428) to me.

If you feel strongly about this policy, please vote on the related feature request: [Question banning should work differently on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109263/question-banning-should-work-differently-on-meta).

Comment: also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/should-the-automated-ban-on-questions-used-on-so-apply-to-meta-as-well

Comment: @AakashM Thank you!  That "relaxed threshold" bit helps me understand the situation a little better

Comment: thanks for asking this question. +1

Answer (score -5):

People always forget that ***deleted questions*** also count towards the ban.

Also, I see it as fair. If somebody makes *multiple* bad [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)s which get downvoted by the community, why should the user be allowed to ask more before proven worthy?

I mean, of course you're allowed to request stuff...but making *many* requests which are going against the nature of this community shows a lack of understanding, in my opinion.

Comment: That's a good point about deleted questions.  I actually did make sure to ask the user if they had any deleted questions.

Comment: If in doubt I'm always with the automated system...because I haven't seen even *one* case where it was wrong or where the devs said "yupp, misfired".

Comment: Who's to say that their feature-requests are **bad**? Just because they go against the prevailing wind of the mob does not mean that they go against the "nature of this community". Ideal and practice are not always the same thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas Agreed.  Bobby, perhaps "unpopular" would be a more accurate adjective?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Mh, good point. Maybe that wording of mine is a little bit too harsh...I meant that the community is going into one direction, and constant "wrong" requests are costing unnecessary time...mh, still hard to say what I mean...

Comment: Bad questions on regular sites are wastes of time. Low-score and controversial questions on Meta sites can still lead to productive discussion. I happen to think that controversy can even be [worth rewarding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101567/meta-sites-should-have-a-badge-for-insightfulness-controversy), if it's on a meta site.