# Should we have some sort of indication that an answer is highly disputed?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, up-votes

When there is significant disagreement on an answer, it is often the case that it will have a net score of 0, or 1, or -1. This is a bit misleading, because the actual votes on the answer might be -6/+5, but only the -1 score is visible. Once you have enough rep you can click and see the +/- votes (that's actually my favorite feature!) but not everyone has this ability, and not everyone who has it uses it all the time... I only tend to use it when I already think there is probably disagreement on a post (either from comments or because I think it's wrong) and I'm curious how others voted.

So, would it be worthwhile to have an indicator of some sort that an answer is highly disputed? The actual threshold for "highly disputed" would be up for debate, but when an answer has a significant enough number of votes to be judged as voted on by a "sample" of the userbase and when the upvotes and downvotes are really close to each other (as in my -6/+5 example) it's pretty clear at that point that the voters do not agree that the answer is correct. But this isn't obvious without seeing the vote breakdowns, and we might have a case of -5/+7, where the answer has net +2 votes and so the casual viewer thinks the answer is correct, even though it's highly disputed.

I don't know exactly what this indicator would be; that can be a discussion for once we've decided if we need this or not. But I'm starting to think we kind of do, because the net vote count can be a bit misleading. Thoughts?

**To be clear, I am *not* suggesting that we display the +/- vote breakdown by default on disputed questions. I'm just wondering if we need some kind of visual indication that there is a lot of disagreement among voters.** (Perhaps we could also allow the score to be displayed on-click if the answer is disputed. But the actual logistics of *how* we'd do this aren't the point; we can iron that out before the feature-request :) I'm just curious if others agree that this is something we might need.)

Comment: Related (but not a dupe): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197169/162102

Comment: The ability to see vote counts, not the delta should be a feature on the mobile site.

Comment: I vote for showing the vote breakdown by default. If this needs two extra database columns, so be it.

Comment: Why don't we just allow viewing vote counts for everybody???

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn "performance issues". Also, I think I've heard "it would be confusing for newcomers".

Comment: @JanDvorak - the upvotes and downvotes are already stored (or at least relatively easily found) separately so there'd be no extra columns needed.

Comment: Disputed questions mostly happen on meta, seldom on SO itself.

Comment: @juergend I'm thinking network-wide, not just on SO (and mostly talking about answers). This has come up pretty often for me on ELL. We'll have answers that are +3/-2 or +2/-2 and so they seem either correct or simply like no attention has been paid to them... But they're just wrong. Sometimes they're right, and have downvotes for some reason. But I just think it would be useful to be able to tell when an answer is disputed, because the net score is misleading in those cases.

Comment: @juergend but, when a SO answer _does_ get disputed, you better stay away from it.

Comment: Wendi, this is an interesting idea.  Have you given some thought to how you define what is and isn't highly disputed?  What about these cases: +1/-2, +2/-1, +3/-2, +4/-2?  Are these the cases included as highly disputed to you?

Comment: @MikePennington I've got a vague idea, though I'm sure it will take a lot of discussion to arrive at a good conclusion :) I think that as the number of votes increases, the threshold between the +/- votes should increase as well. Ex. +3/-2 might be disputed, not a lot of votes and they're only 1 apart. Change that by one to +4/-2 and maybe that's not disputed because the numbers are so low. But if there are a *ton* of votes, let's say +15/-25, that's still pretty disputed even though they're 10 apart. I'm sure we can play around with it to get the numbers to work out right :) (cont'd)

Comment: @WendiKidd or just show the vote split in every case :-)

Comment: +1/-2 (same as +2/-1 in my view) is a special case for me; the numbers are so low that I'm inclined to say that there's not enough data to mark it as disputed yet. But then, we might change that particular threshold for smaller sites where there are less votes. +3/-2 I would mark disputed, and +4/-2 is perhaps an edge case as I mentioned above. We'd have to play around with that one :)

Comment: Isn't the comment count a good enough indicator?

Comment: Or maybe a total + agreement? agreement = abs(score) / votes

Comment: @Gilles Unfortunately not everyone comments when they downvote. Or one person comments, and then others see a comment has already been left and find that sufficient (I rarely see "this is wrong" comments upvoted, either).

Comment: @WendiKidd I always upvote "this is wrong" comments if they indicate my downvote reason

Comment: This might be particularly useful on Per Site Meta posts, which sometimes have hugely controversial answers with close to zero scores

Comment: @Rory [I once suggested making a badge for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101567/meta-sites-should-have-a-badge-for-insightfulness-controversy). Others have suggested badges for the same thing [on non-meta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34543/can-we-have-a-badge-for-controversy) and [on Area 51](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52185/can-we-have-a-badge-for-controversy-on-area51).

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn, it is available for everyone through the API. You can hook the API up to the browser to make it always work for you on all sites, regardless of rep: http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The actual threshold for "highly disputed" would be up for debate

Yeah, well... It's kinda hard to determine whether we need this or not without having actual examples of posts that might benefit from it. My gut feeling is that "controversial" is a pretty bad sign; if folks are that divided as to the worth of a post, there's probably something about it that could stand to be fixed.

But hey, let's throw something together and see what pops up:

```sql
declare @dumpDate as DateTime = (select max(CreationDate) from Votes);

select top 100 PostId as [Post Link], count(*) TotalVotes,
  Round(count(case when VoteTypeId=2 then 1 else null end)*100.0 / count(*),1) UpvotePct
from Posts p
join Votes v on v.PostId=p.Id
where VoteTypeId in (2,3)
and p.CreationDate > @dumpDate-30
and PostTypeId=##postType##
group by PostId
having count(*) >= 8
  and count(case when VoteTypeId=2 then 1 else null end)*1.0
    / count(*) between 0.33 and 0.67

order by count(*) desc
```

That'll give you some "controversial" questions or answers (PostTypeId=1 or 2) from the last 30 days of the data dump. Turns out, there aren't all that many controversial answers; here's what I got<sup>1</sup> for the last 30 days<sup>2</sup>:

- [Different rounding with println and printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141257/different-rounding-with-println-and-printf/20141475#20141475)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043406/php-find-similar-substring-between-two-string/20043570#20043570
- [Is it possible to include C++ libraries in C programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324863/is-it-possible-to-include-c-libraries-in-c-programs/20324895#20324895)
- [What is the difference between dynamic dispatch and late binding in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187587/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-dispatch-and-late-binding-in-c/20187724#20187724)
- [C# huge performance drop assigning float value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410149/c-sharp-huge-performance-drop-assigning-float-value/20410264#20410264)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242798/how-to-create-mini-versions-of-my-code/20242921#20242921
- [Insert in middle of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098893/insert-in-middle-of-list/20098925#20098925)
- [Random.Next() always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412155/random-next-always-returns-0/20412156#20412156)
- [Why is there not a constructor for List<T> that takes a params argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870215/why-is-there-not-a-constructor-for-listt-that-takes-a-params-argument/19870239#19870239)
- [Can VideoView be detach and reattached without stopping the stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696466/can-videoview-be-detach-and-reattached-without-stopping-the-stream/19873413#19873413)
- [Is separating MySQL code from PHP code a standard, common practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136891/is-separating-mysql-code-from-php-code-a-standard-common-practice/20138266#20138266)
- [Refactoring minimum method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364292/refactoring-minimum-method/20364315#20364315)

Now, are those really worth *calling out* as controversial in some fashion?

---

Just realized you're thinking about smaller sites; here are *all* of the answers meeting this criteria on ELL:

- [What's the accepted way to use "criterion", "criteria", "criterions"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158/correct-usage-of-criteria/161#161)
- [Why is "a Japanese" offensive?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183/why-is-a-japanese-offensive/185#185)
- [My mom or our mom?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6702/my-mom-or-our-mom/6704#6704)
- [Why is 'what will you do tomorrow evening' incorrect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9102/why-is-what-will-you-do-tomorrow-evening-incorrect/9103#9103)
- [It is expected that . . .?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11075/it-is-expected-that/11076#11076)

Meh. I guess I could see this as perhaps an interesting 10K tool.

---

<sup>1<sub>Data.se is in kind of a bad way right now, so I just ran these internally; YMMV.</sub></sup>
<sup>2<sub>There are 5270 answers matching these criteria for all time on Stack Overflow</sub></sup>

Comment: Fair enough. I also note that most of those examples have plenty of comments, so perhaps what I really should be putting effort into is making sure that incorrect answers on my site have comments clearly explaining the problem (especially when the votes don't match the incorrectness of the answer). I agree that if it's controversial there's probably something wrong with it, but sometimes a wrong answer is just a wrong answer (I can't edit to fix without completely changing it) and I feel like my lonely comment isn't enough, especially when the downvote disappears in the net score. But I

Comment: definitely see the point you're making, and I think you're right that my suggestion is probably overkill compared to the actual problem I'm seeing. I appreciate you pulling up a set of questions to look at; that helped clarify this for me! :)

Comment: See my edit, @Wendi - I wasn't paying attention to who posted this discussion, else I'd have put ELL data in there from the start.

Comment: +1 for the 10k tool! Highly controversial posts should be a indicative that something weird is going on.

Comment: I actually think this would be most interesting (though not necessarily useful...) on meta stackoverflow. Here's where most of the big controversies actually happen. But probably not particularly useful here either, since here it's not indicative of anything very cohesive, and certainly not of something wrong.

Answer (score 8):

This makes sense especially in cases where a now-incorrect answer is accepted. Such an answer can have amassed dozens or hundreds of upvotes over time, and it can take a long time for it to get voted "back down".

On the other hand, suddenly showing the up-/downvote ratio would likely be confusing for many users.

You can also make the case that it isn't really needed: on highly disputed answers, comments will usually show what's up. Also sometimes, people will take the law in their own hands, and apply an edit.

Comment: Don't think that it'd be confusing. I'd say people are used to seeing vote breakdowns on many places on the Internet.

Comment: I don't mean to say that we should show the upvote/downvote ratio; I'm just pulling this out of thin air, but maybe the "indicator" is that the net score is colored red. Some kind of visual indication that says "hey, the net score here might be misleading." (Optionally, on such answers, allow the score to be clicked to view net score regardless of the user's rep.) The comments argument doesn't work for me, at least on ELL; the reason I'm suggesting this is because I see so many wrong answers with disputed votes at +1, -1, or 0, with no comments explaining why they're wrong.

Comment: @slhck but not on Stack Overflow, where it's a privilege for 1k+ users . It would suddenly show up for only those relatively few highly contested answers.

Comment: So while I agree that comments *could* alleviate the problem, and possibly should... In my experience, they don't. :/ I'm left with a lot of disputed answers with misleading net scores... And often these answers are *accepted*, which is troublesome.

Comment: @Pëkka also, those who have a desktop browser with the right userscript that I constantly use.

Comment: @Wendi can you point to a single highly disputed answer where there are no comments that point out what's wrong with it?

Comment: Stack Exchange also decides to color buttons black or change the top bar, or switch all the close reasons and flag dialogs. Seeing all votes would be one of the *less* confusing things.

Comment: @Pëkka do hidden-by-def comments count as not present??

Comment: @Jan not really, IMO. If you are going to use an answer, you better read the comments.

Comment: Agreed. Start showing the breakdown _now_, when the top bar has recently appeared.

Comment: @Pëkka I was just looking at one recently, which is why I posted this... Unfortunately my browser has a million tabs all the time, so I'm having trouble finding it again. I probably should have just included a link in the question. I'll keep looking and come back when I find it.

Comment: @Pëkka hmm... most people who trust w3schools or use for..in to loop an array don't read comments either. They copy-paste the top-voted or green-ticked answer and move on. I think we want them to get better code from us, too.

Comment: To be clear re: your edit, I am *not* suggesting that the vote breakdown appear on contest answers. I am suggesting that we in some way indicate that there is a dispute in voting.

Comment: @Wendi OK, editing that paragraph

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an unfortunate artifact of using "upvotes minus downvotes" as your score.

There are methods that are arguably better -- see e.g., [Sorting answers, given overvotes and undervotes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26833/2921), which shows how to take into account the statistical confidence in the overall rating, given the votes -- but my impression is that the StackExchange folks have decided the current method is "good enough".  That's understandable.

I agree with you that this does come up occasionally and it would be nice to have a way to enable people to notice that the answer is disputed before using it.  I wonder if a better way to deal with it might be by improving which comments are shown.  Usually a highly-disputed answer will have comments indicating the problems with the answer, so if we can have some comment sorting algorithm that maximizes the likelihood that those comments are noticeable and get noticed, that might be an alternative way to deal with highly disputed answers.

Comment: I agree with the comment... (ahem) comment