# Debatable questions/answers, public insight on vote counts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, down-votes, up-votes

**Some context:**

[This thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts) provide some insights as to why vote counts are not displayed by default.

It is, for me, a rather unsatisfying reason. Not because it is not valid, but because it really is a shame that something that helpful has a restrained access for a very technical down-to-earth reason...

Now, I'm not sure showing the vote counts publicly for every post is the solution either. But first, why I think getting ***some information*** as to how much debate there is over a post is important.

**Why I think such info might be useful:**

I believe a 0-average or even a negative-average vote count may still have merit if 10 people voted up and say 10 people voted down (or even 11).

I feel negative votes put a lot of pressure on the poster (and that's good that it makes you re-think your answer), but sometimes, things are not that black and white.

Not to mention that there is quite a trend factor, I could sometimes witness some mimetism, to a mild extent of course. I think it is good for a user to see what the community thinks as a whole. Average votes are one thing, but is it significant all by itself? I am unsure.

Talking about peer pressure, when your post is down-voted, you (should) consider removing it, but if people are divided about it, then it might have some merit if only to show that, that people are divided about it.

**Hence my feature request:**

I think it would be interesting ***to have a way to measure how debatable (and debated) a question/answer is***. If you can't show the votes ***explicitly***, then I suggest something like an attribute saying that people are debating over it.

For instance, if a post has received more than ***n*** votes we might provide attributes like:

- "***unanimous***", if most post go in one direction
- "***debatable***"/"***debated***"/"***discussed***"/"***subject to discussion***" or even "***to be considered carefuly***" (although this one seems biased), if there are many votes on either side

Of course, ***n***, ***most*** and ***many*** are yet to be defined.

Not to mention that doing this instead of showing vote counts has two good points on top of provided that information:

- only posts with more than ***n*** votes would be featuring this, so overall, the overhead is reduced,
- the accusation that less-experienced users might use vote counts to balance out questions/answers doesn't hold anymore since the vote count is unkown and since it requires many votes, adding one isn't that significant.

**Discussion:**

I think there is much to debate on this one.

What do you think? Why do you think it is a good/bad idea? Do you see the merit of such a feature? Do you even agree that such a feature would help the users evaluate their answers and those of others?

Comment: [Users with 1000 rep](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) _can_ see vote counts.

Comment: My point exaclty. An established user can probably guess whether it is debatable or not... What about normal users? What about public vote view

Comment: It looks to me as if those who have the priviledge are the ones who need it least. I'm talking about using this info to see whether a question/answer is relevent for you as a random user, to make sense of neither-white-nor-black posts

Comment: [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69852)

Comment: Thanks. Do you want me to remove my duplicate?

Comment: That's entirely up to you. If you want, you can change your question to address the new information.

Comment: I updated my question in the light of the thread you provided.

Comment: I protest against this thread being closed. I updated this thread heavily 47 minutes ago and made it very distinct from the thread it was previously a duplicate of. The revision history is proof of that. I honestly believe those who made the final call did not take the time to review it correclty or at the very least tell me of what this thread is a duplicate in its current state.

Comment: For the record, I didn't vote to close as duplicate, but as "problem does not exist" because it didn't seem you were aware of the background. Now, however, I think this is a duplicate of [Should we have some sort of indication that an answer is highly disputed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210683/should-we-have-some-sort-of-indication-that-an-answer-is-highly-disputed?rq=1)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation