# lost points deleting answer

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, deleted-answers, score

I had an answer with -1 score, I deleted it, and now I got -2 penalty on the downvote and -6 for deleting the question.

```
-6  14 hours ago    removed     Jade - Controlling line-breaks in the HTML output
-2  15 hours ago    downvote    Jade - Controlling line-breaks in the HTML output
```

I just want to check with you if this is a new behaviour (I remember deleting my downvoted answers and normally I was getting back the points).

I tried to search for this in google and here and could not find an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: related: [Do answers that attract both positive and negative votes benefit the community?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226126/165773)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post had one upvote and two downvotes.  That's a net score of -1 and a net reputation change of +6.  Deleting the post reverses all of the reputation changes, including both downvotes and the upvote, for a total change of -6.

Comment: tks to look at that, if the answer is negative -1 the correct action is to delete it anyway right? I mean to clean the site from doubtfull answers?

Comment: @SantiagoRebella: Negatively-voted answers are sometimes held up as examples of what a *wrong* answer looks like.

Comment: @SantiagoRebella You have to ask yourself whether or not you think that the post is helpful or not helpful.  If you think that the post is helpful then you should keep it around.  If you think that it's not helpful then you should delete it.  While the score can help inform that decision, there are many other factors to take into consideration.  At the end of the day, do you think someone is going to be better off or worse of for reading your answer when looking at this question when they have the same problem?